# can't setup Sublime Text 3 & SFTP

Tags: sftp, sublimetext3

I have installed SFTP using the Package Installer (control+shift+p), but now when i hit on "Add new server", no matter which file i am, it just added the code/json i have to enter my username/pass and so on. and i do this and then nothing happens. I wanted videos and the guy in the video open a new file and put there the setting of the ftp and when he clicked on SFTP: Browse the new connection was there, but i dont see mine. it never show up. what im doing wrong. im stuck and i need help. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

same problem here. in the usage tutorial, Will says that the server config needs to be saved under sftp_servers/ folder, but doesn't say where this folder needs to be. I'm guessing this is the problem.

update:

I figured this out by looking around. The Command "browse packages" takes you to a folder where all the packages are installed, and there is the User/sftp_servers/ folder. If you copy your server config file to this folder, you should be able to browse the servers.

Comment: `$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/User/sftp_servers`

Comment: What is `server config file`. Where can I see that. I am trying to setup SFTP  in sublime 3

Comment: you can create a server config file using the command (via the command palette) `sftp: setup server`

Answer (score 3):

If you have a **Windows PC**, you can use **[Swish](http://www.swish-sftp.org/)**.
It will create a folder that is a remote connection to your **SFTP**.
And best part, it's free.

Open your files in Sublime and get all sync.

Here is a how-to: http://www.howtogeek.com/165893/how-to-integrate-a-remote-sftp-directory-into-windows-explorer/

Answer (score 1):

Actually i watched this video in YouTube and then saw how i have to setup my SFTP and now it finally it is working like it should be. :)

[Sublime Text 2 Tutorials #11 - Sublime SFTP Folder Sync With Map To Remote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6NqBGHFfm0)

Answer (score 0):

While installing the SFTP make sure to select the "Install For" is set to "All Users" and "Default Text File Type" is set to "Unix/binary". I am sure this is the issue that is not letting you work properly on it.

Comment: should i save my config for the ftp in a new file in my project and what should be the file name. can i name it whatever i want or?

Comment: Yes you can save it in a new file that would not be a problem and renaming it anything would be good enough.

Comment: when i do this it popup "Add new server" again and my just added server is not listed there :( I guess the problem is with me, but i dont know what im doing wrong :( im noobie...

Comment: They should have the native option for sftp connection, like Komodo has.

Answer (score 0):

For sublime text 2

```
./Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/sftp_servers
```

For sublime text 3

```
./Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/sftp_servers
```

So lets say you saved your "server setup" text file to your desktop as "foo".
Open a terminal and do the following.

```
cd ~/Desktop
cp foo ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/User/sftp_servers/
```

This will make it available to sublime text's SFTP package. * you may/may not have to restart sublime.